# Rails form - step between new and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a step between new and create on a standard rails form, I want to send the params from my 'new' action to 'confirmation' to 'create'.

How do I post the data from the 'confirmation' action to create without creating the same (hidden) form from my 'new' action and setting every value via my @order variable?

I've tried sending the @order variable via link_to

```
=link_to orders_path(order: @order), method: 'post', class: 'f-sub' do
      =image_tag "confirm.png"
```

but I receive the error that my order_params is empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You could store the object in the session until the confirmation page.

In your form :

```
<% form_for Order.new, url: save_session_path do |f| %>
```

In your controller :

```
def save_session
  session[:order] = params[:order]
  redirect_to confirmation_path
end

def confirmation
  @order = Order.new(session[:order])
end
```

2 - Pass the object through the controller actions

In your form :

```
<% form_for Order.new, url: confirmation_path do |f| %>
```

in your controller :

```
def confirmation
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
end
```